# Android: Textview imageGetter display html content and image. Cache image of ImageGetter

Tags: android, image, textview, browser-cache

I am new in Android Programming. Currently, I am developed an application to display HTML content in TextView by using ImageGetter and Html.fromHtml(). Is it possible for me to cache the content and image in TextView in order I can view the image offline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Some days ago i was doing the same. I was displaying `html` with textview using ImageGetter. But it wasn't giving the proposed result. So then i used Jsoup libaray and i extract the elements and display them in `Textvew` and when `img` tag comes i display the image in `Imageview` using UIL universal image libarary. Well this libaray has Option of cacheing the images. 
You only need to cache the html string then pass it to the folllowing class along with layout rest jsoup and UIL will handle.

```
public class PostContentHandler {
Context context;
String  content;
LinearLayout linearLayout;
public PostContentHandler(Context context, String content , LinearLayout linearLayout){
    this.context=context;
    this.content=content;
    this.linearLayout=linearLayout;

}

public void setContentToView(){
    List<String> p = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> src = new ArrayList<>();
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(content);

    Elements elements = doc.getAllElements();

    for(Element element :elements){
        Tag tag = element.tag();
        if(tag.getName().matches("h[1-6]{1}")){
            String heading = element.select(tag.getName().toString()).text();
            TextView textView = new TextView(context);
            textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            textView.setTextSize(20);
            textView.setText(heading);
            textView.setPadding(5, 0, 5, 0);
            textView.setTextColor(R.color.black);
            linearLayout.addView(textView);
        }

        if(tag.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("p")){
            element.select("img").remove();
            String body= element.html();
            TextView textView = new TextView(context);
            textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(body));
            textView.setTextColor(R.color.black);
            textView.setPadding(10,0,10,0);
            linearLayout.addView(textView);
            p.add(body);
        }
        if (tag.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("img")){
            String url  = element.select("img").attr("src");


            final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
            imageLoader.displayImage(url, imageView, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                    super.onLoadingComplete(imageUri, view, loadedImage);
                    int height=loadedImage.getHeight();
                    imageView.getLayoutParams().height=getScreenWidth();
                    imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                    imageView.requestLayout();

                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                    super.onLoadingStarted(imageUri, view);
                }
            });

            linearLayout.addView(imageView);
            src.add(url);
        }

    }
}
public static int getScreenWidth() {
    return Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
}
}
```

Comment: May I know how can I call this function, how can I pass the html string into this function? Sorry I am new in Android Programming.

Comment: Use image view to display image. not textview

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Finally I figure it out your code. However, on the line of imageLoader.displayImage() has syntax error. It come out   error Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ImageLoader must be init with configuration before using

Comment: You will get that error you haven't configured Universal Image Loader libaray

Comment: I had configured with Universal Image library. It shows no error now but I still not able to display picture.

Comment: I had share my code on the comment below. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code. I try and debug, it shows the code goes to onLoadingFailed() and does not go to onLoadingComplete(). I have no idea why.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
     DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheOnDisc(true).cacheInMemory(true)
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
            .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(100)).build();

    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
            getApplicationContext())
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
            .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
            .discCacheSize(10 * 1024 * 1024).build();

    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
    setContentToView();
}

public void setContentToView(){
    List<String> p = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> src = new ArrayList<>();
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(content);
    Elements elements = doc.getAllElements();

    for(Element element :elements){
        Tag tag = element.tag();
        if(tag.getName().matches("h[1-6]{1}")){
            String heading = element.select(tag.getName().toString()).text();
            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(heading));
            textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            linearLayout.addView(textView);
        }


        if(tag.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("p")){
            element.select("img").remove();
            String body= element.html();
            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(body));
            this.linearLayout.addView(textView);
            p.add(body);
        }


        if (tag.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("img")){
            String url  = element.select("img").attr("src");
            final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
            imageLoader.displayImage(url, imageView, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                    super.onLoadingStarted(imageUri, view);

                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                    super.onLoadingComplete(imageUri, view, loadedImage);
                    int height=loadedImage.getHeight();
                    imageView.getLayoutParams().height=getScreenWidth();
                    imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                    imageView.requestLayout();
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {
                    super.onLoadingCancelled(imageUri, view);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                    super.onLoadingFailed(imageUri, view, failReason);
                }
            });

            linearLayout.addView(imageView);
            src.add(url);
        }
    }
}

public static int getScreenWidth() {
    return Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
}
```